# How to sort an array with two values, weight first value 1.5 times?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sorting, array-multisort

I want to sort a **multidimensional** array. With only one key it's no problem at all.

```
$value1 = array();
foreach ($dataArray as $key => $row)
{
    $value1[$key] = $row['value_a'];
}
array_multisort($value1, SORT_ASC, $dataArray);
```

Now I want to sort the above array with two values, `value_a` and `value_b` and weight `value_a` 1.5 times. value_a is a distance e.g. 300 feet and value_b is a price e.g. 450. Just to give you some context...

`array_multisort` is able to sort an array based on two values but not weighting them differently.

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Thanks a lot for your effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `usort`, which takes a callback so you can define any comparison behaviour you like.

In your case, something like:

```
usort($value1, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['value_a'] * 1.5 + $a['value_b'] - $b['value_a'] * 1.5 - $b['value_b'];
});
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Update: There is a note on the above manual page that the result of the callback will be rounded to an integer, therefore you might want to consider your own rounding within the callback (e.g. if the amounts are dollars you could multiply everything by 100 to get an integer value)

Comment: thank you leftclickben! I'll have a look a that. How would you handle the comparison of a price and a distance?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean -- you can use whatever keys you like just change `value_a` and `value_b` to what you need.  (?)

Comment: So for example you have a list of restaurants and want to find one with a moderate distance and price within your reach...

Comment: That sounds more like filtering than sorting.  If you want to only show values within a certain range, then you need to filter out the ones outside of that range.  That's different from sorting, which only changes the order of an array, it doesn't add or remove elements.  For filtering check `array_filter`

Comment: I already filtered my results. I am calculating the distance in mysql and get the 25 nearest for example. Then I am calculating the price (I'cant calculate the price in mysql because of the complexity I am not a mysql expert at all :))). So I have two values distance and price within the array. I either can sort using the price or the distance but I want to combine them. I think usort can help here. but how can I compare a distance and a price. Should I set some kind of scroring?